# docker buildargs via JSON?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to build a docker image and am trying to use docker-api to achieve this. The intent is to pass buildargs to the docker image using docker api: https://www.rubydoc.info/github/swipely/docker-api/Docker%2FImage.build_from_dir
The documentation says in order to pass buildargs to the `opts` to the api above:

> JSON map of string pairs for build-time variables. Users pass these
>   values at build-time. Docker uses the buildargs as the environment
>   context for commands run via the Dockerfile RUN instruction, or for
>   variable expansion in other Dockerfile instructions. This is not meant
>   for passing secret values. Read more about the buildargs instruction.

The following code works with just 't' (tags).

```
Docker::Image.build_from_dir(Dir.pwd, 't' => "MyTag", 'buildargs' => "{ABC = > 'abc', CDE => 'cde'}")
```

However, when I add the 'buildargs' I get the following error:

```
Excon::Error::Socket: Broken pipe (Errno::EPIPE)
  <internal:prelude>:134:in `__write_nonblock'
  <internal:prelude>:134:in `write_nonblock'
```

Comment: The string you have as `buildargs` isn't valid JSON.  You might generate an ordinary `Hash` of the arguments and then call `#to_json` on it.

Comment: thanks. JSON.generate(params) did the trick